# python subprocess.pyc “no such file or directory”

Tags: python, linux

I have a Python script and I have a mistake about subprocess.

My algorithm:

```
import re
from subprocess import call
import pylab
thickness = [0.005,0.006,0.007,0.008,0.009,0.01,0.011,0.012]
Fn1 = []
Fn2 = []
Fn3 = []

for tick in thickness:

fid = open("modal2.inp","w")

data = open("modal.inp").read()
fid.write( re.sub("\*THICKNESS",str(tick),data))
fid.close()
  call(['ccx_2.5','modal2'])
 data = open('modal2.dat').read().splitlines()[7:]
Fn_1 = float(data[0].split()[3]) # frequency 1 in Hz
Fn_2 = float(data[1].split()[3]) # frequency 2 in Hz = frequency 3
Fn_3 = float(data[3].split()[3]) # frequency 4 in Hz
Fn1.append(Fn_1)
Fn2.append(Fn_2)
Fn3.append(Fn_3)
```

I searched and saw similar mistakes; however, I do not understand how I should edit my algorithm.

My mistake;

```
\lib\subprocess.pyc in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite)
894                                          env,
895                                          cwd,
--> 896                                          startupinfo)
897             except pywintypes.error, e:
898                 # Translate pywintypes.error to WindowsError, which is

WindowsError: [Error 2] no such file or directory
```

Comment: Is the program installed in your $PATH? Otherwise you should use `'./ccx_2.5'` or other path

Comment: I do not pay attention the $PATH. I writed script in my working file.

Comment: What happens if you run the part of the script up to the subprocess call, then `ccx_2.5 modal2` from the command line in same directory? That should hopefully be informative.

Comment: What is your OS? Why `WindowsError` in the traceback but `linux` tag on the question? Have you tried to specify the full path (including extension) for `ccx_2.5`? If you are on Window, you could use raw string literal and pass the whole command as a string: `subprocess.check_call(r'c:\Program\ Files\ccx\ccx_2.5.exe modal2.dat')`